# PHP/SQL - DateTime class - how to add automaticlly time if it's not inserted by the user

Tags: php, sql

Now I sq use the `DateTime` class to convert to different time formats and I find it very useful except one feature. Before when the user try to add date but for some reason skip the time I got `00:00:00` for the time which was good enough for me. Now, with the `DateTime` class if the time is not included it return error.
  Here is my code:

```
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y H:i:s", $data['event_time']);

    if($dt === false)
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid date");
    }

    $formattedDate = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Every time I try to insert date without time I get `Invalid date` error. Is there a way to insert zeros on the place of the time, except getting error for this?

Thanks

Leron

Comment: `$data['event_time'] .= ' 00:00:00'` ?

Comment: And what about the users that have entered time? I need a check and do something only if time is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some simple pre-validation:

```
$date['event_time'] = trim($date['event_time']);
if (preg_match('/^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$/', $date['event_time'])) {
    $date['event_time'] .= ' 00:00:00';
} else if (!preg_match('/^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/', $date['event_time'])) {
    die('Invalid format');
}
```

Comment: Yeap, this is what I need, generally I try to avoid regex when possible, but still it works.

Comment: You can write it without Regexen if you want, it's just going to be longer... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex I guess this should work too. If i was you I would use @deceze solution instead of this :P but for the sake of completeness, here it is:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y H:i:s", $data['event_time']);

if($dt === false)
{
    $data['event_time'] = trim($data['event_time']);
    $data['event_time'] .= " 00:00:00";
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y H:i:s", $data['event_time')
    if ($dt === false) {
      throw new Exception("Invalid date");
    }
}

$formattedDate = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks gonna have this in mind but I also think @deceze's solution maybe is better, so I'm gonna accept his answer. Thanks both.